# How to define sequence of Map value in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have defined one map value in Spring XML file.

*-spring.xml file

```
<util:map id="ruleEvaluationService" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="CFN" value-ref="cfnRuleEvaluationService" />
    <entry key="PH" value-ref="phRuleEvaluationService" />
    <entry key="MPG" value-ref="mpgRuleEvaluationService" />
</util:map>

<bean id="ruleEngine" class="com.medtronic.b2b.core.cvg.service.impl.RuleEngineImpl">
   <property name="ruleEvaluationService" ref="ruleEvaluationService" />
</bean>
```

I need to maintain a sequence of Map value in such a way that first CFN value evaluate, if doesn't match then PH and further MPG value. My thinking was if i will give the entry in Map in a correct order, i will get the same sequence in my java file as well. But the same thing is not happening.

RuleEngineImpl.java

```
@Resource(name = "ruleEvaluationService")
private Map<MedtronicB2BRuleType, RuleEvaluationService> ruleEvaluationService;

// some code

public void setRuleEvaluationService(final Map<MedtronicB2BRuleType, RuleEvaluationService> ruleEvaluationService) {
    final Map<MedtronicB2BRuleType, RuleEvaluationService> map = new LinkedHashMap<MedtronicB2BRuleType, RuleEvaluationService>();
    for (final MedtronicB2BRuleType key : ruleEvaluationService.keySet()) {
        map.put(key, ruleEvaluationService.get(key));
    }
    this.ruleEvaluationService = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

}

Here I am writing a login in setter method to fill map in correct sequence.
But if I am printing Map, getting wrong sequence

`Set<MedtronicB2BRuleType> ruleTypeSet = ruleEvaluationService.keySet();`

Result  : **[PH, CFN, MPG]**

Why I am not getting sequence like CFN, PH, MPG. What is the correct way to define sequence in spring.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap, in that case your order will be maintained.

```
<util:map id="ruleEvaluationService" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap ">
```